# Check if array records are the same

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've got a select option in which i put some values depending on an array. For instance we could have something like

```
[{
  name: 'A',
  type: 'a',
},
{
  name: 'B',
  type: 'b',
},
{
  name: 'B',
  type: 'b',
},
{
  name: 'C',
  type: 'c',
}]
```

my select option values are for example

```
myOptions: any[] = [
        {name: 'City', value: 'city'},
        {name: 'State', value: 'state'},
        {name: 'Region', value: 'region'},
    ];
```

now, what I have to do is:

```
if the array contains all records have type "a", then my options should be myOptions[0]. 
If the array contains all records have type "b", then my options should be myOptions[1].
If the array contains different records have type, then my options should be myOptions[2].
```

the array values is variable. the options of the select not.
This is the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  aArray = [
    {
      name: 'A',
      type: 'a',
    },
    {
      name: 'A',
      type: 'a',
    },
    {
      name: 'A',
      type: 'a',
    },
  ];
  bArray = [
    {
      name: 'B',
      type: 'b',
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      type: 'b',
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      type: 'b',
    },
  ];
  difArray = [
    {
      name: 'A',
      type: 'a',
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      type: 'b',
    },
    {
      name: 'B',
      type: 'b',
    },
    {
      name: 'C',
      type: 'c',
    },
  ];

  myOptions: any[] = [
    { name: 'City', value: 'city' },
    { name: 'State', value: 'state' },
    { name: 'Region', value: 'region' },
  ];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.difArray.every((value, i, array) => {
      array.map((x) => {
        if (value.type === 'a' && x.type === 'a') {
          console.log('a');
        } else if (value.type === 'b' && x.type === 'b') {
            console.log("b");
        } else {
            console.log('generic');
        }
      })
    });
  }
}
```

that's the html

```
<select>
  <option [ngValue]="null" disabled selected>test</option>
  <option
    *ngFor="let option of myOptions; let i = index"
    [value]="option.value"
  >
    {{ option.name }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: And what did you try ? Where do you struggle ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle i've just tried to check the types but to be honest, i feel to be very far from the final result. I'm stuck

Comment: Well, it's working actually. Yeah, I was close. Thank you, now I got it right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.aArray.forEach((object:any)=>{
          if( aArray.name === "a"){
              this.option == object[0]
          }
          else if (aArray.name === "b") {
              this.option == object[1]
          }
           ....
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `every` and `find`.

If I understand the rule correctly, you have to check that every entry of `aArray` can be found in `difEntry`, which translates to this :

```js
if (aArray.every(entry => difArray.find(difEntry => difEntry.type === entry.type && difEntry.name === entry.name))) {
  console.log('Contains all entries from A')
} else {
  console.log('Does not contain all entries from A')
  // Repeat with bArray etc
}
```